# awk sed if statement

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am trying to add 0 to the beginning, IF there is a "." at the 2nd character of that line. I couldn't combine these two;

```
awk '{ print substr( $0, 2, 1 ) }' file.txt
```

showing the second character

```
sed -ie "s/.\{0\}/0/" file.txt
```

adding a zero to the beginning.

There should be an "if the second character is a dot".

sample file:

```
1.02.2017 23:40:00
10.02.2017 23:40:00
```

final:

```
01.02.2017 23:40:00
10.02.2017 23:40:00
```

Answer (score 13):

We may use either of `sed` or `awk` to completely solve the problem.

---

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^.\./0&/' file.txt
```

When `&` occurs in the replacement part of the substitution command (`s`), it will be expanded to the part of the input line that matches the pattern part of the command.

The regular expression `^.\.` means "*match all lines that starts with (`^`) an arbitrary character (`.`) followed by a literal dot (`\.`)*".

If the line is `1.02.2017 23:40:00`, the pattern will match, and `1.` would be replaced by `01.` at the start of the line.

---

With `awk`:

Building on the partial `awk` code in the question...

This will, as stated, print the second character of each line of input:

```
$ awk '{ print substr($0, 2, 1) }' file.txt
```

We can use the fact that `substr($0, 2, 1)` returns the second character and use that as the condition:

```
$ awk 'substr($0, 2, 1) == "." { ... }' file.txt
```

What goes into `{ ... }` is code that prepends `$0`, which is the contents of the current line, with a zero if the preceding condition is true:

```
$ awk 'substr($0, 2, 1) == "." { $0 = "0" $0 }' file.txt
```

Then we just need to make sure that all lines are printed:

```
$ awk 'substr($0, 2, 1) == "." { $0 = "0" $0 } { print }' file.txt
```

The condition `substr($0, 2, 1) == "."` may of course be changed into a regular expression too (we use exactly the same expression as we used in the `sed` solution):

```
$ awk '/^.\./ { $0 = "0" $0 } { print }' file.txt
```

Some people who thinks "shorter is always better" would write that as

```
$ awk '/^.\./ { $0 = "0" $0 } 1' file.txt
```

(and probably also remove most spaces: `awk '/^.\./{$0="0"$0}1' file.txt`)

Comment: +1 Your last AWK example or your sed example are the correct ways to do this. Note, for clarity, that it would only be one or the other.

Comment: In my opinion the "correct" approach (which doesn't fiddle with spaces and which is lighter weight anyway) is your final version, **`sed 's/^.\./0&/' file.txt`**.  I think you should put that at the start of this answer.  Still, +1.

Comment: @Wildcard We aim to please.

Answer (score 5):

With sed:

```
sed -e "/^.\./s/^/0/" file.txt
```

The pattern `/^.\./` looks for any character and a literal dot at the start of line `^`, and if that matches, `s`ubstitute that start of line  with a zero, effectively adding the zero to the start.

The sed expressoin `s/.\{0\}/0/` is somewhat odd, it matches zero or more copies of anything and replaces with a zero. The pattern will of course match in every position of the string, but since `s///` only replaces the first match, it works as you intended. A quaint way to do it, though.

---

Or with awk, a similar regex would work to match the line, but we can use `substr`:

```
awk 'substr($0, 2, 1) == "." {$0 = "0" $0} 1' file.txt
```

We first test if the second character is a dot, then add a zero to the front of the line if so. The final one invokes the default action of printing the line after any modifications.

Answer (score 4):

You said awk and sed, but it seems like you are trying to format a date and for that I would use the `date` command. For instance:

```
echo '1.2.2017 23:40:00' | sed 's/\./\//g' | xargs -0 date '+%m.%d.%Y %T' -d
```

will output

```
01.02.2017 23:40:00
```

The `sed` command in the middle changes the periods to slashes for input into `date -d`. The format options allow output in almost any format you want. The `%m` in particular will zero-pad the month, which is what it seems like you are trying to do.

As Kusalananda points out:

Even more compact (GNU date and Bash): `date -f <(tr '.' '/' <dates.in) '+%m.%d.%Y %T'`

Comment: Nice catch! Even more compact (GNU date and Bash): `date -f <(tr '.' '/' <dates.in) '+%m.%d.%Y %T'`

Comment: Whenever I have Slashes in my patterns, but no Pipes: `s|\.|/|g`. Otherwise, as noted above: Nice catch, +1

Answer (score 2):

A different strategy than presented in the other answers: You could use "." as the field separator.

```
awk -F. '$1 < 10 {printf "0"} {print}' /tmp/in.txt
```

You could golf this to:

```
awk -F. '$1<10{printf "0"}1' /tmp/in.txt
```

For sed, there is a shorter command, presented in another (great) answer.

Comment: Alternative:  `awk -F. '{print ($1<10?0$0:$0)}' file`

Answer (score 1):

With sed it could be

```
sed 's/^\(.\)\.\(.*\)/0\1.\2/'
```

This will use `^` to anchor to the beginning of the line, then capture any single character in a group, followed by a literal `.`, then anything else.  If we match that we print a `0`, then our first capture group (the character at the start of the line), then a `.` then our second capture group (the rest of the line)

Comment: It's not at all necessary to do any of that capturing. `&` is your friend. See Kusalananda's sed example.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson not necessary, but given there are other examples already this shows another feature of `sed` that could be useful in other situations, not just this specific problem